# Как упростить код синхронизации данных между "dataGridView1" и "textBox"?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Текущая запись из "dataGridView1" отображается в "textBox1".
Пользователь в "textBox1" вносит изменения.

Как сохранить изменения из "textBox" в базу данных и отобразить в "dataGridView1"?

Прилагаю код моего решения.
Если на форме будет несколько "textBox", "checkBox1", то делать для каждого элемента событие, как-то хлопотно...

Как упростить код синхронизации данных между "dataGridView1" и "textBox"?

```
public partial class Frm1UC : UserControl
    {
        DataTable dt;        

        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder;


        static string catBD = @"c:\vs\db_GridVAccess.accdb";
        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", catBD);

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM TreeFolder_tbl";


        public Frm1UC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Frm1UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);


                dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }


        // Выбор ячейки
        private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }

        // Событие. Изменение текста
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = textBox1.Text;
        }

        // Сохранить
        public void Save()
        {
            adapter.Update(dt);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Save();
        }


    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В заголовке у вас "как сохранить значение в БД", а в самом сообщении описываются проблемы привязки модели к gui-контролам. Так о чём вопрос в самом деле?

Comment: _делать для каждого элемента событие, как-то хлопотно_ - ну, не делайте. Пусть данные, введённые пользователем, теряются. То-то он обрадуется...

Comment: Так вы отредактируете сообщение: в чём именно заключается ваш вопрос? Вам хочется упростить код синхронизации данных между гридом и текстбоксами? Или всё же проблема в работе с БД?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Обновил вопрос. Я правильно вас понял?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [привязку данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding) (data binding), чтобы не обрабатывать вручную все события изменения данных.

Вот вам полный пример приложения. Загрузка данных в `DataTable` сделана вручную прямо в коде, у вас вместо этого будет использование `DataAdapter` и т. п.

К досаде, приходится "помогать" корректной работе `DataGridView`, для чего сделаны обработчики событий `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` и `BindingSource.BindingComplete`. Можно и без них, но тогда данные обновляются не мгновенно, а лишь после изменения текущей *строки* грида.

В примере используется `DataTable` с тремя колонками, две из которых: `name` и `birthdate` - привязаны к `TetxBox` и `DateTimePicker` соответственно. Этим я показал, что привязка возможна к разным типам данных.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        TextBox textBoxName;
        DateTimePicker dateTimePicker;
        Button buttonLoad;

        DataTable dataTable;
        BindingSource bindingSource;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Width = 400;

            dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            textBoxName = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = dataGridView.Bottom + 20 };
            dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker { Parent = this, Top = textBoxName.Top, Left = textBoxName.Right + 50 };
            buttonLoad = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Load", Top = textBoxName.Bottom + 20 };

            dataTable = new DataTable();
            bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

            dataGridView.CellValueChanged += DataGridView_CellValueChanged;
            bindingSource.BindingComplete += BindingSource_BindingComplete;
            buttonLoad.Click += ButtonLoad_Click;
        }

        private void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource.EndEdit();
        }

        private void BindingSource_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.BindingCompleteContext == BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate && e.Exception == null)
            {
                e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.EndCurrentEdit();
            }
        }

        private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // тут должна быть загрузка данных из БД в dataTable
            dataTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("birthdate", typeof(DateTime));
            dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "foo", DateTime.Now);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "bar", DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));

            // Привязка данных
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;

            textBoxName.DataBindings.Add(
                nameof(TextBox.Text), bindingSource, "name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

            dateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(
                nameof(DateTimePicker.Value), bindingSource, "birthdate", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Примечание: привязку данных нужно делать повторно после каждой загрузки данных.