# Как связать две таблицы с помощью DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

У меня есть две таблицы Timetable и Services связанные по ID_Service. Timetable представлена как DataGrid. Мне нужно чтобы в Timetable появился новый столбец вида DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, который бы заполнялся значениями из столбца Name_service таблицы Services. Причем этот столбец должен согласовываться с ID_Service, т.е. в выпадающем комбобоксе я выбираю значение, и согласно этому значению в столбце ID_Service устанавливается айди. 
Я совсем новичок в этом, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно такое реализовать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал полный пример приложения. Его можно скопировать и запустить.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();            
            Width = 500;

            var timeTable = new DataTable("timeTable");
            timeTable.Columns.Add("ID_Timetable", typeof(int));
            timeTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            timeTable.Columns.Add("ID_Service", typeof(int));

            timeTable.Rows.Add(6, new DateTime(2019, 05, 18));
            timeTable.Rows.Add(7, new DateTime(2019, 05, 17));
            timeTable.Rows.Add(8, new DateTime(2019, 05, 16));


            var services = new DataTable("services");
            services.Columns.Add("ID_Service", typeof(int));
            services.Columns.Add("Name_service", typeof(string));

            services.Rows.Add(1, "Foo");
            services.Rows.Add(2, "Bar");
            services.Rows.Add(3, "Baz");


            var bindingSourceTimeTable = new BindingSource();
            bindingSourceTimeTable.DataSource = timeTable;

            var bindingSourceServices = new BindingSource();
            bindingSourceServices.DataSource = services;


            var serviceNameColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            serviceNameColumn.DataSource = bindingSourceServices;

            serviceNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID_Service"; // внешний ключ
            serviceNameColumn.DisplayMember = "Name_service";            
            serviceNameColumn.ValueMember = "ID_Service"; // первичный ключ


            dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSourceTimeTable;
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(serviceNameColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

В примере два `DataTable` заполняются вручную прямо в коде. У вас они должны заполняться из БД.

Создаются два `BindingSource`. Каждый привязывается к своей таблице. Один из них привязывается к `DataGridView`, второй - к столбцу `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Остаётся лишь правильно задать свойства `DataPropertyName`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` - именно они важны для работы кода.

Более полный пример можно найти [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/3437d394-588b-459f-a26e-998d022ae258/-datagridview?forum=fordataru).

Предвосхищая возможные вопросы о немгновенном обновлении данных в ячейках грида, смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911728/184217) обработку событий `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` и `BindingSource.BindingComplete`.

Comment: на счет обновления действительно возник вопросик. Методы я добавил, а  как здесь осуществить привязку по аналогии с 'textBoxName.DataBindings.Add(
                nameof(TextBox.Text), bindingSource, "name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);'

Comment: @hope25 - Это никак не относится к теме первоначального вопроса. Задайте это отдельным вопросом (создайте новую тему).