# Изменение ячейки с помощью combobox в datagridview

Tags: c#

Есть код по заполнению таблицы. Но никак не разберусь как заставить изменять значение в столбце "Код поставщика" при изменении значения в combobox в столбце "Поставщики". Буду признателен за подсказки и помощь.

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
string query = "select Договор.*, Поставщики.Название from Договор, Поставщики where Договор.[Код поставщика] = Поставщики.[Код поставщика] order by [№ договора]";
command.CommandText = query;

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
Поставщики.DisplayMember = "Название";
Поставщики.ValueMember = "Код поставщика";
Поставщики.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Название"].ReadOnly = true;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982898/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вроде сделал как там, но пишет что поле с именем не существует в serviceNameColumn.DisplayMember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось вот так

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

string query = "select * from Договор";
string query1 = "select * from Поставщики";

conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn);

dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Договор");
dataAdapter1.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Поставщики");

dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet);

BindingSource dogSource = new BindingSource();
dogSource.DataSource = dataSet;
dogSource.DataMember = "Договор";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dogSource;

BindingSource postSource = new BindingSource();
postSource.DataSource = dataSet;
postSource.DataMember = "Поставщики";

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboColumn.HeaderText = "Поставщики";
comboColumn.DataSource = postSource;

comboColumn.DataPropertyName = "Код поставщика";

comboColumn.DisplayMember = "Название";

comboColumn.ValueMember = "Код поставщика";
```