# Как сделать чтобы числа в ячейке в БД Access вставленная в dataGridView менялись в зависимости от изменения другой ячейки

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Скажите пожалуйста можно ли проводить математические операции c ячейками БД Access вставленных в dataGridView? то есть я имею ввиду что есть сумма полученная к примеру от заработной платы в одной строке. и сумма полученная от премии в другой. мне нужно сделать чтобы в столбце итого они складывались если это относится к доходу и отнимались от итогового дохода в строке расход. вообщем как в exel в столбце  Итого.Доход = Сумма.Заработная плата + Сумма.Премия. 
Итого.Расход = Итого.Доход - Расход.Транспорт
и т.д. то есть в последующем сумма расхода отнималась от оставшейся Суммы.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace HomeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "база_данныхDataSet.Accounting". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.accountingTableAdapter.Fill(this.база_данныхDataSet.Accounting);

        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accountingTableAdapter.Update(база_данныхDataSet);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddForm ad = new AddForm();
            ad.Owner = this;
            ad.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchForm sf = new SearchForm();
            sf.Owner = this;
            sf.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [DataColumn.Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: я сейчас по другому написал. складывает и вычитает как надо, но с небольшой задержкой пока не тыкнешь курсором на какой нибудь ячейке. хотелось бы как нибудь быстрее это сделать.   '   dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));'

Comment: и так для каждой столбца и строки. плюс хотел бы еще узнать как можно сделать чтобы при добавлении новой строки, она сразу распознавалась как доход  или расход и сразу прибавлялась к последней строке дохода или отнималась от последней строки расхода?

Comment: По поводу первого вашего комментария. Ну, раз не хотите делать правильно, то возитесь с событиями `DataGridView`. В частности, нужно обрабатывать `CellValueChanged`. Возможно, поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911728/184217.

Comment: А вообще, ещё правильней сделать модель данных: класс с нужными свойствами. Часть свойств будут вычисляемыми.

Comment: я про это DataColumn.Expression уже завтра почитаю изучу. сейчас только информацию собираю что и как можно. а не подскажите как это "ещё правильней сделать модель данных: класс с нужными свойствами. Часть свойств будут вычисляемыми. "