# c# datagridview не сохраняет без enter

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView почему то отправляет данные в БД (MS Server), только если я при вводе в табличку (при ее изменение) нажимал на Enter или если я через button update табличку. Как сделать чтобы без нажатий на enter делал?
Пояснение, если я в ячейке изменяю данные то без нажатия на enter в каждой из измененных ячеек (как я понял) данные, которым я не применил Enter не отправятся.

Comment: Я, конечно, за C# не шарю, но описанная Вами ситуация очень похожа на то, что на ячейке стоит слушатель onSubmit. Т. е. данные будут сохраняться и передаваться на сервер только при сабмите, т. е. нажатии на Enter или кнопки Submit (если таковая имеется). Попробуйте вместо этого использовать слушатель onChange: он срабатывает, когда данные в поле изменяются.

Comment: Надо вызвать Commit для строки по событию CellEndEdit, но там есть свои приколы, сейчас уже не вспомню, лет 8 прошло, но я это победил в своё время

Comment: На такие "вопросы" у меня есть стандартный ответ: ошибка в строке 123. / Хотя бы укажите, что такое `datagridview`, из какой он GUI-библиотеки? Как в него данные попадают: напрямую или с помощью привязки данных? Какие обработчики событий есть? А как данные берутся из грида, для отправки в БД?

Comment: Так вам нужен ответ? Или вы пришли просто поплакаться? | Продолжу гадать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911728/184217 Обратите внимание на обработку событий `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` и `BindingSource.BindingComplete`.